# Successfully Installed Python 3.1.2 but When Using the Command to check if its installed on my PC, it doesn't recognized the set of commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, 64-bit

I have already installed Python 3.1.2 on my window 7(64bit) .However when I checked if its successfully installed using this command : `python --version`I still got an error as "python" is not recognized..". Then I using  the command `setx PATH "C:\Python 31"`, error message shown *setx is not recognized.."*

I have checked that Python 31 was shown under my C drive and i have already open the PYTHON GUI window

Please i need help on where i get this wrong

Comment: if you have it open why do you need to check if its installed? surely you would only check if you couldnt open it

Comment: After the setx, what do you get when you type PATH?  Could it be one of those 32-bit/64-bit problems?  Are you running from a 32-bit or 64-bit cmd prompt (look at the title bar - system32 = 64 bit, syswow64 = 32bit).

Comment: I checked it, its C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe..but my operating system is  64 bit.please adviced

Comment: after i type setx..i get setx is not recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you mean that you want to try and use it to see if it works and recognized from the command line.

Verify that your python bin folder is in your system path. You can follow [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537574%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from msdn, or any other guide to add the python bin folder to the path environment variable.

The path you'll want to add is where `python.exe` is located, probably at `C:\Python31\bin"` or similar.

Comment: I did but still not working.. please can you check my reply to "Cup" above..if this may be the issue.thanks

Comment: It doesn't has to do with what I suggested - have you checked in the system path if it contains the python path? have you tried adding it manually?

Comment: Hi@arieljannai..What you said above it works for me...using the guide i added the ;C:\Python31 on the environmental variable path